# Distinguish queries run by user directly, from internal queries, in log files

Tags: postgresql

When checking log files, there is a lot of internal/system queries (runned internally by pgadmin tool for example) and not directly executed by user.
I there any way to distinguish which queries run by user directly, and which is internal queries?

(btw, config params I use for logging: `log_statement=all` and `log_min_duration_statement=0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "internal/system queries". Unless you use auto_explain with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on`, PostgreSQL will only log the queries that get sent by the client.

It may well be that some of these queries are internal queries of your database driver or application server, but PostgreSQL doesn't know that. For that, you'd have to enable logging at a component that has that information.

Comment: I mean there is a lot of queries, logged as   `application_name=pgadmin tool`, but not directly ran by user.  few examples: `statement: SELECT format_type(oid,-1) as typname FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 20` or `statement: SELECT CASE WHEN typbasetype=0 THEN oid else typbasetype END AS basetype
  FROM pg_type WHERE oid=20`
`

Comment: PostgreSQL cannot distinguish those statements from others.